# Templating HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, function, templates, include

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to clone/template HTML that is frequently repeated in my web app. For example, I have a voting `<form>` (see below) that needs to be located on several pages.

Two ways I thought of doing this:

1. a function call, e.g., `voteForm($action, $user_id, $formType, $success);`
2. an `include` statement, e.g.,  `include '/myApp/views/voteForm.php'`

I prefer an `include` statement b/c:

1. Then I don't have to decide on the function's parameters which may change over time forcing me to rewrite the function calls everywhere they exists in my app. With the `include` statement, I can just use the variables as they are wherever I put the `include`d php file (avoiding redeclaring them which is a pain b/c there are often lots of variables).
2. I can write the HTML in HTML and not as a PHP string where I have to deal with escaping characters/json_encode issues.

Should I reconsider using `include` instead `function()` for any reasons (e.g., performance)? Are there are other templating solutions I'm not thinking of?

```
    <form action="<?=$action?>" method='post' data-form-data='{'formType': '<?=$formType?>', 'success': '<?=$success?>'} >`
    <input type='hidden' value='<?=$user_id?>' name='user_id'>
    <input type='radio' value='1' name='vote'>
    <input type='radio' value='-1' name='vote'>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really up to you--you could have a hybrid of a `function` that calls `include` for you (setting up any necessary variables that the include file may need for display purposes). e.g.

```
function createForm($action,$foo,$bar){
  $form_action = $action;
  $form_foo = $foo;
  include('templates/form.inc');
}
```

As far as performance, there's no huge benefit that I'm aware of. Although If you're looking for a better way for templating, you may want to look at [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or some other system that handles most of the 'tough work' for you.

Just keep in mind that when you have code outputting HTML you no longer have a separation of concerns. That is to say that if you decide to change the look and feel of the site at a later date you're not looking through just `.inc` (or whatever extension you've used) files, but now both `.inc` *and* `.php` files to apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid putting HTML into function calls. I think what your trying to achieve here would be best suited to an include statement - based on personal preference.

As for performance - it's hard to tell but you could use a PHP Profiler like XDebug to see whether a function or include is the most efficient.

http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: What is your reasoning for saying one should "avoid putting HTML into function calls"?

Comment: I think it's personal preference - I think the HTML should be kept in the main page / view itself rather than clutter up your functions.

Answer (score 0):

For big blocks of generated HTML, I'd recommend using includes. I prefer to use function calls to get specific bits of data back.

The again, this is personal preference and cannot be answered with a truly 'correct' answer.

In terms of performance, I would guess not much difference at all unless you're making thousands of calls on each one in one go.

Hope that helps.

Comment: by "thousands of calls on each" you mean thousands of `function()` calls or thousands of `includes`? And do you know which one is more performant?

Comment: I haven't done any tests, but in reality, it's not really worth testing. The difference would be so extremely small. Like a fraction of a second; possibly not even that. Build it first and THEN work to optimize if it's causing you problems. It's usually a bad idea to optimize before your app is even built.